# What are "denied hosts"?

Tags: security, hosting

An absolutely noob question I'm sure but I get an email from my web host everyday with a list of a few denied hosts and wondered exactly what this meant. I'm guessing that its a connection refused by the host because of an identification problem but what exactly could cause this issue?

Additionally, I receive the following message and wondered if someone could explain it to me:

reverse mapping - checking getaddrinfo for blah.blah.com [190.xxx.xxx.xx] failed - POSSIBLE BREAK-IN ATTEMPT! : 9 time(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Denied hosts" refers to brute force attacks on your services (usually ssh). Most likely you have a software like denyhosts or fail2ban or similar that looks into the failure log  and when a host reaches a predefined number of failed logins it bans it (semi-)permanently. 
A brute force dictionary attack usually looks like this: hacker launches some tool that checks for public services(be that ssh for simplicity) running on machines in some IP range. When such a service is discovered the tool tries very common (hence dictionary) combinations of username/passwords. Things like "root/test123" or "guest/guest" should come to mind.

You don't need to do anything besides making sure that your passwords are strong enough and you don't run any unsecured services on your box. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_policy might be of some help in choosing strong passwords.